# How to specify custom CSS classes for WTForms custom fields / subfields

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

How do I specify sperate custom classes for subfields in a multi-field WTFForm field / custom field?

I created a form with one field that is a custom field to make list box of checkboxes:

```
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()
```

That field is placed on a form:

```
class Categories(FlaskForm):
    categories = MultiCheckboxField()
```

The form is rendered with Jinga:

```
@app.route('/test/', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    form = Categories()
    form.categories.choices = categorylist()
    return render_template('test.html', form=form )
```

I specify a custom class name in the template that gets assigned to the  element correctly

```
        {{ form.categories(class = 'custom class') }}
```

That renders the UL with the desired class name to the `<ul>` but not the underlying `<li>` items in the list.  I want to specify a *different* class name to the `<li>` elements:

```
<ul class = "custom class">
   <li></li>
```

I want to set a **different custom class** for the underlying elements in the custom field, in this case a `<li>` element, but could be something else for another custom field.   I am stumped where to hook in this custom sub-field class name in the process.   Any help is appreciated.

Ideally:

```
<ul class = 'custom class'>
<li class = 'another custom class'>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.